# How to find Bluetooth Profile Versions for HFP, PBAP on iPhone/Android

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, hfp, bluetooth-profile

I am generating report for my Automotive head unit with references to all the phone Bluetooth profiles like HFP 1.6 for iphone 5

Is there a way to find out what HFP version is supported in iPhone 7 and all other versions iphone and Android devices

Example :

iPhone 7/Model - MN9V2LL/A has Bluetooth version 4.2 , What is its HFP, PBAP, A2DP, AVRCP and MAP versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a tricky way using Bluetooth Sniffer

Capture SDP Packets from Sniffer
Search for Response form Master/Slave
Bluetooth Profiler Descriptor List shows the UUID and Version Supported

[image]

Comment: Could you tell what software were you using? I could not find it as "Bluetooth Sniffer".